# Get entity that doesn't conform to HasCollision at CGPoint

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

So after lots of RealityKit development on the new iPad with the lidar camera, I noticed how heavy are entities that conform to the HasCollision protocol.
If you think about it, it makes total sense.
The ARKit core must keep on tracking these entities mesh in order to delegate when there's a collision with the virtual world, that constantly being built from the surrounding physical environment.

So using entities that conform to HasCollision is not usable for me. Now, it creates a problem with the raycasting as it only works against collisionable entities.

And though of alternative ways to do raycasting against simply ModelEntitys?

Comment: What do you mean with "heavy"? In terms of performance? You could try to initialize your `Entity` with a custom `CollisionShape`

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you could try is disabling the entities' collision components by default, and only when doing a ray cast enable it on all entities, and after the cast disable it again on all. Maybe the moment of casting will cause a bit of a lag spike, but theres only one way to find out :D